# Headline for an article is : "No playoffs for either Team A or Team B". What does it convey?

Tags: either-or

Does it mean neither of them will be in the playoffs? Or does it mean that one of them will be in the playoffs?

Comment: Wouldn't the article under the headline answer this for you?

Comment: Even without the **either**, the title means none for A and none for B. **Either** makes it surer. I'd call it a headline for an article rather than an article for a headline.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Fixed it, and thanks for the input!

Comment: Inherently, there is ambiguity between the two readings you offer. Negation plus 'or/nor' is messy at the best of times.  But without prior context, pragmatics makes the 'neither team reached the playoffs' far and away the more likely. But later context could force the alternative sense: "No playoffs for either Bluepool City or Muncaster United – it's mathematically impossible for both teams to reach the playoff stage.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You might just go for it: Manchester United and Liverpool or Manchester City. I doubt they'd come after you.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for your comment. I reached similar conclusion upon first reading the headline.

Comment: You can guess based on your knowledge of sports and the competition the teams are involved in (headlines often require significant knowledge), but you may have to read the article to be sure.

Comment: @StuartF I posted this question to get clarity on the usage of either-or. 
You are right, but that doesn't answer the question I asked. Thanks tho!